# Python: Loading Complex numbers from file saved in Mag, Degrees

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using the technique outlined [here](http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2014/003/) for loading and plotting an S-Parameters file.

It assumes each row of the file is a frequency in Hertz in the first column followed by 4 Complex numbers in Real,Imag format (so, 8 more columns).

It's using Numpy to load those as follows:

```
data = map(lambda x: [ x[0],
                       complex(x[1], x[2]) ],
           numpy.loadtxt("file.s2p", skiprows=1))
```

In my case, my file is in Mag[dB],Angle[degrees] format as follows (just showing the first set of complex numbers):

```
# Hz    S11 Mag[dB]     S11 Ang[deg] 
10000   7.184891e-003   1.799854e+002
10093   7.844427e-003   1.799862e+002
10185   7.364107e-003   1.799857e+002
```

Is there an easy way to change the text file loading to make it load the Mag and Angle and convert them to Real,Imag format so the rest of the script can stay the same?

Is that a change that should be integrated into the loading, or should the loading be changed to just load the numbers (i.e. not as complex entries), and then manipulate them separately in a subsequent step?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like `Mag * np.exp(1j * np.deg2rad(Ang))`?

Comment: Conversion after loading would be easiest.  `loadtxt` should give you a 2d array.  `Mag` would be `data[:,1]`, and `Ang` `data[:,2]`.

Comment: These two suggestions worked. I like the Matlab-ish array accessing suggested by @hpaulj , and the conversion suggested by Paul worked correctly. I compared to some calculations I had done in an Excel sheet and confirmed. If either of you want to put these comments together into an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.